# What is a state-of-the-art, practical, and economical solution to get a Linux from online that installs Intel MKL?

Tags: cloud, virtual-machine, intel, intel-mkl

I am working on an old Mac (Early 2013 machine) and need to run something from Intel MKL. I would like to avoid using my Mac to run Intel MKL, and I heard there could be ways to run a virtual machine on a cloud. So, what is the state-of-the-art and yet practical solution for doing so? Sorry I am quite ignorant about the capability of cloud computing, but I guess one can have a Linux system running on a nIntel CPU remotely that can be accessed online, and then Intel MKL can be installed there, am I correct, and how that can be done?

Comment: Pretty sure it doesn't NEED to me an Intel CPU and it should run on that old Mac too. Assuming then that the issue is the age (and hence performance) of the machine, you just need access to ANY other computer. For cloud, I don't know what you can get for free, but if you are willing to pay (price depends on requirements, hard to say much more without details) there are loads of options, unsurprisingly. However, depending on your situation there might be other, possibly better, options, but you did not provide nearly enough information for me to suggest anything specific.

Comment: @Qubit: It does have to at least be an x86 CPU, but a 2013 Mac is in the middle of Mac's x86-64 Intel era.  If it was an old PowerPC Mac, it wouldn't run MKL except in a slow emulator.  I assume zell wants to run on something more powerful than an old Haswell or Sandybridge, though; an old Mac would be fine to develop and test on, but throughput is not as good as a modern CPU with more cores and higher sustained clocks, and more memory bandwidth.  (And with AVX2 + FMA, if that 2013 machine isn't Haswell.)

Comment: Of course, running on newer hardware will hopefully be faster. But getting access to something like that depends on his circuimstances. In academia for instance, it's relatively simple. Outside, I imagine it's hard to get something for free outside limited trial periods, but I could be wrong. In any case, installing MKL is usually not a problem, given that it is free software.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Intel Devcloud is the one that you are looking for.
Intel DevCloud is a cloud service provided by Intel that comes with pre-installed Intel optimised frameworks, tools and libraries where you can get the oneMKL library as well. Intel Devcloud offers complimentary access to a wide range of intel architectures to help you get instant hands-on experience.
You can try creating a devcloud account by registering using the below link
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/forms/idz/devcloud-registration.html?tgt=https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/secure/forms/devcloud-enrollment/account-provisioning.html
and to know more about how to connect and use Intel devcloud, you can get the details from the following link
https://devcloud.intel.com/oneapi/documentation/shell-commands/
Hope the provided information helps.